# Roughly how big could the tidal range be on a human habitable Earth analogue world?

Tags: science-based, earth-like, gravity, tides, tidal-forces

The Gravitational tidal forces can be supplied by any orbiting moon(s)/twin planet(s) of any mass and any orbital radius, inclination or orbital radius, but the system must be stable for at least 10,000 years. The period from low tide to high tide must be a month or less. Roughly means order of magnitude, 0.1km, 1km, 10km, 100km (bonus if any extra accuracy can be provided).

Very large tides would provide a lot of interesting scope for story line development. My concern is that they are either not possible on the scale I would like, would result in an unstable orbital arrangement or would be too short lived due to frictional drag.

Comment: I you are serious about 100 km tide i don't think this can be done. The consequences of the planet would be catastrophic and may cause the moon just to fall into it. While i am certainly no expert about this topic i think the best solution is something magical and not something scientific.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock I disagree, what makes it interesting is what is allowed by physics and trying to work within those constraints. If magic is used then anything is possible and it turns into a just so story. I'm not sure what is possible tide wise that's why I asked for a rough estimate to the nearest order of magnitude. We know that 0.01km is possible as that more or less happens happens on Earth so that just leaves 0.1km, 1km, 10km and at the furthest crazy end 100km. 1000km seemed just to far fetched and 100km might also be but hopefully someone can shed some light on it.

Comment: I didn't say that it is not a very cool idea. I just said that it's basically impossible using only normal physics. If you want an easy solution i suggest maybe the moon being like a strong magnet for water. This would fix a lot of issues though i don't know if it would give us levitating water masses or something and a lot of tsunamis. Such things your world would likely have to just deal with.

Comment: Yes I'm thinking 100km+ tides are not possible, but sometimes people dig out amazing facts so who knows. Seems like your thinking has it in the 0.1-10km range...A strong magnet for water sounds interesting, although I think that's what gravity does.

Comment: Yes but it would be just for water and not everything else. This prevents constant earthquakes and other weird anomalies. I think you can get away with it in this manner. It would probably only become really weird when have 1000km+ tides. And generally i would say it would really interesting what cultures develop in such a world. Especially if maybe certain tides last decades or something like that.

Comment: One extra bit if the tides as you pointed out last less then a month it would make ocean travel probably as good as impossible. Just pointing this out as it may be of use to you.

Comment: An interesting point. No doubt you are correct at some level of tidal influence, however that point might be fairly extreme at 100km a tide would only extend the size of the planet by 8% and over tens of thousands of km the gradient would not be that much. But I am more interested in what happens on land with a civilization adapted to this monstrous rise and fall. This would only work in the low km tide height ranges, but in those cases there might well still be permanent dry land and a vast intertidal area to explore - if you were quick. But first steps are to see what's possible tide wise.

Comment: They would probably primarily settle on permanent dry areas. Though there may be some fortifications in low tide areas furthermore a smaller settlement is also an option. Though generally infrastructure in the low tide areas would be probably kept to minimum as it's difficult to build there. If your sentient species is amphibious or can better build in water things would be very different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152241/discussion-between-fallenspacerock-and-slarty).

Comment: The lengths given such as one Km. What is meant by those? Is that intended to be the height delta between low and high tide?

Comment: I think it is how far the water recedes during a low tide.

Comment: @Gault Drakkor yes the difference between high tide and low tide. I'm interested in trying to find out what is physically possible. Although the story might use a lesser value depending on the answers.